# VSCode extension to view all committed files and the folder structure in the local repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a python project in visual studio code where some of the files are committed into the local git repository. When using extensions like `Git Graph` or `Source Control` I only see the commit history and for each what file was inserted, changed or deleted.
But I am looking for a way to see after each commit or at least for the last commit how the python project is looking like in the local repository.
When I push my commits to a remote repository like `BitBucket` I am able to see this going to the tab `Source` on the `BitBucke` web page. Is there something similar for my local repository in visual studio code?

Comment: just checkout a commit ID and the files are as they where in that commit

Comment: if you can't find one why not write one

Comment: In `gitk` the lower right window pane by default shows *Patch* mode, but you can switch it to *Tree* which I think is what you are asking for.

Comment: @hlovdal Thank you. That is exactly what I am looking for. Is there an vscode extension like this? The vscode gitk extension does seem to have this feature.